# Is there any way to rebuild the Dalvik interpreter and run it without invoicing a full VM?

Tags: android, dalvik, native-code

I want to rebuild the Dalvik interpreter to add some security features to protect my code. Is there any way to run only a Dalvik interpreter without invoking a full Dalvik virtual machine?

Comment: As somebody just voted -1 I'll add some notes: I do know how to run the build-in VM and generally run native code. I also do know that there is a portable interpreter inside the dalvik code. What I wanted to know is if it is possible to compile that interpreter and run it in some kind of standalone mode from inside the app.

Comment: I think this is a valid and interesting technical question, so I +1 it and looking forward to competent feedback.